# jQuery animate fails

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate a UL on a button click. It works if i simply change the margin-left but fails when I try to animate. Here is the code:

```
 $(".btn_right").click(function(){

        var curLeft=$("ul#questions").css('margin-left').replace("px", ""); //Current left margin
        var newLeft=curLeft-245; //Set to required 

        alert(newLeft); //Confirm New margin left

        //$("ul#questions").css("margin-left",newLeft+"px"); - THIS WORKS
        $("#ulquestions").animate({marginLeft: "23px"}, 500); //THIS DOESNT

        return false;
    });
```

I think I am just overlooking a simple mistake. Any ideas guys? The js console is not giving me any error.

Thanks.

Comment: i see that the selector is different in the line that works and the one that doesnt. could this be the problem?

Comment: FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU....I knew it was something simple. I think I have been coding a lot and I need some rest.Thanks a ton Th0rndike.

Comment: np, sometimes you just need another pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are different

`$("ul#questions"`) vs `$("#ulquestions")`

Try this

```
$("ul#questions").animate({marginLeft: "23px"}, 500);
```